# Relationship between .css, .sass or .less

Tags: css, sass, less

I am a pure designer, so I totally new to the field of front-end development.

I have learned what is LESS, what is SASS.

But when I open a HTML template, there are some LESS or SCSS files, but also a lot of CSS files. I am quite confused what's the relationship between LESS/SCSS and CSS?

If LESS/SCSS is so good to use why people still write 10 thousand lines in CSS file, which is impossible for me to read through..?

Are those CSS files like "bootstrap.css" or "animate.min.css" just libraries for LESS/SCSS to use? Or what other relationship between them?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of frameworks ship with not only the LESS and SASS files, but also the results of those files (the exported CSS files). In the case of Bootstrap, this is particularly true: none of the ".css" files are libraries for the LESS. They are the result.

The authors of these frameworks assume that some people want the LESS/SASS workflow, and others want to include the CSS and be done with it. So they include it all. In many cases, the ill-documented sprawling CSS files are actually demonstrating that the assumption about LESS ("so good to use") is not always true. Writing CSS without a preprocessor and with best practices will more often result in a smaller more readable (and well-documented) file than a LESS/SASS-based workflow.

Having spent some time with LESS, I think I might be ready to move back to straight-up CSS.

Comment: Gerg, thank you so much for your instant comment, this is quite helpful for me to understand how LESS works. So... the CSS files are probably included by authors in case some people want to see the CSS code directly? So... can LESS work independently without any CSS file?

Comment: Frank, LESS doesn't truly work independently. I think there is a client-side tool but it's not recommended for production. The files feed a pre-processor which takes in the directives and spits out CSS. At the end of the day, CSS is always the result. The authors just include this result for those who are not using a pre-processor workflow or otherwise aren't set up to build the LESS files (or aren't interested in doing so).

Comment: Oh, I see~ Really appreciate your kind comments on my such entry-level question.